# Removing extra tabs from indented code using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I've my PHP code something like this:

```
$a = [
   "code" => "
        if(a == b) {
             doSomething();
        }
        ",
   // ...
];
```

Now if I echo `$a['code']` in a whitespace preserver tag like pre or textarea, I get:

```
        if(a == b) {
             doSomething();
        }
```

whereas I want:

```
if(a == b) {
     doSomething();
}
```

See those extra tabs/whitespaces in real output? How can I **preserve indentation of code** while removing extra tabs from every line?

I can do a regex of something like `(\t){3}` and replace it with `""` but is there any better way?

Comment: If the indention are spaces and the extra whitespace are tabs you could use `str_replace()` instead of a regex. Otherwise you probably have to use regex.

Comment: @Xatenev not really. they're mixed up because I used different editors while writing these codes in various files so I don't think they are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PHP doesn't have a built in way to achieve this. I've often done very strange things with indentation by default.

It's a good standard in many situations not to mix indentation from different domains but it's a hard standard to enforce (it's also very awkward with interleaving).

For example in views:

```php
<?php if(x): ?>
<html></html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In complex template may actually be preferable to:

```php
<?php if(x): ?>
    <html></html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That is HTML indented with HTML, PHP with PHP. In the above case you would tend to rely on syntax highlighting to make things clearer.

If you don't mind about performance you might get away with something such as this:

```php
function prune_outer_whitespace($str) {
    // IPTF who uses weird line endings.
    $lines = explode("\n", $str);
    // IPTF who uses multiline for single line.
    assert(count($lines) > 2);
    // IPTF who has an opening quote with content.
    assert($lines[0] === '');
    array_unshift($lines);
    // IPTF who didn't put the terminating quote on its own line.
    array_pop($lines);

    // IPTF who mixes indentation characters.
    assert(preg_match('/^([\t ]+)/', $lines[0], $matches));
    $start = $matches[1];
    $length = strlen($start);

    foreach($lines as &$line) {
        if($line === '') continue;
        // IPTF with insufficient indentation or non-empty empty lines.
        assert(strlen($line) > $length);
        // IPTF with insufficient indentation or mixed indentation.
        assert(!strncmp($start, $line, $length));
        $line = substr($line, $length);
    }

    return $lines;
}
```

Untested and for use with:

```php
$str = '
    if a
        b()
    else
        c()
';
$str = prune_outer_whitespace($str);
```

You can take a performance hit with this though and end up with strange behaviour. You'll need conventions that are kept to and what works for one string type or string content might be more inconvenient for another.